# How to run keras on ubuntu20 on termux with backend as theano

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, ubuntu-20.04, termux

I tried to install theano and keras on Pydroid 3 (Android) which I was successfull  but while running keras theano wasn't the backend for keras so I installed ubuntu 20 on termux and installed keras and theano with the following command:-

`apt install python3-keras --no-install-recommends && apt install python3-theano --no-install-recommends`

and it was successfully installed and when i wanted the backend stuff as `theano` I searched for `~/.keras/keras.json` but it wasn't there so anyway I wanted to check it so I ran it gave me the following error:-

```
root@localhost~# python3 testkeras.py
[localhost:21091] opal_ifinit: ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR) failed with errno=13
[localhost:21092] opal_ifinit: ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR) failed with errno=13
[localhost:21092] pmix_ifinit: ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR) failed with errno=13
[localhost:21092] oob_tcp: problems getting address for index 88256 (kernel index -1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------     No network interfaces were found for out-of-band communications. We require
at least one available network for out-of-band messaging.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[localhost:21091] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Unable to start a daemon on the local node in file ess_singleton_module.c at line 716
[localhost:21091] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Unable to start a daemon on the local node in file ess_singleton_module.c at line 172                   --------------------------------------------------------------------------     It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

  orte_ess_init failed
  --> Returned value Unable to start a daemon on the local node (-127) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  ompi_mpi_init: ompi_rte_init failed
  --> Returned "Unable to start a daemon on the local node" (-127) instead of "Success" (0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init_thread
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[localhost:21091] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
```

**1.) I want to know what was the problem .**

**2.) Suggestions are welcomed.**

***The Code that I ran if any of you want to know***

```
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
```

**And here is the modules I have installed :**

```
Package             Version
------------------- -------
decorator           4.4.2                                                      h5py                2.10.0
Keras               2.2.4
Keras-Applications  1.0.6
Keras-Preprocessing 1.0.5
mpi4py              3.0.3
numpy               1.17.4
pip                 20.0.2                                                     PyYAML              5.3.1                                                      scipy               1.3.3
setuptools          45.2.0
six                 1.14.0
Theano              1.0.4
wheel               0.34.2
```

**And I'am a new to this machine learning field**

**Some other information on the system**

```
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      root@localhost
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     --------------
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS focal aarch64
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Kernel: 4.4.147+
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Uptime: 18805 days, 10 hours, 9 min
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   Packages: 202 (dpkg)
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   Shell: bash 5.0.16
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Terminal: proot
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   CPU: Unisoc SC9863a (8) @ 1.200GHz
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Memory: 957MiB / 1819MiB
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Comment: So the testkeras.py file only contains those imports? What if you just open a python shell, and import keras? What is the output in this case?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Yes I will try that.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy it gave me the same output

Comment: These errors make no sense to me, I do not see why MPI is involved here, that is why I asked for exact code. Also there are inconsistencies in your platform, like the uptime cannot be 18805 days (that is over 50 years).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dr. Snoopy , I finally got it working correctly . But I had to delete the os and reinstalled it without any need by using the command `apt install proot-distro` from termux but I think the real problem was the command
`apt install python3-keras --no-install-recommends` as like you said there were some unsatisfied dependencies or platform inconsistencies.

**Okay finally the steps to be done to get it working**

**1.** Enter the following command in termux `apt install proot-distro && proot-distro install ubuntu-18.04 && apt install python3-keras`

**2.** And then use the favourite text editor to edit the file I use vim in this case `vim .keras/keras.json`
***The file would be like the following:***

```
{
    "floatx": "float32",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "backend": "tensorflow",
    "image_data_format": "channels_last"
}
```

and change the value of backend to theano in my case I ad theano
***the file should be like the following:***

```
{
    "floatx": "float32",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "backend": "theano",
    "image_data_format": "channels_last"
}
```

And then save the file.And test it by getting into python interactive mode and enter `import keras`
The output should be `Using Theano as Backend`
***I think this should help someone out there.***